# How to prevent the case when parameters do not match in yield?

Tags: ruby

For example, it causes problem when I use yield(param) but pass a block {|p1,p2| ...} which has two parameters. How should I prevent this if I do not know what parameters yield takes a head of time?

Comment: How does it cause problems? I tested this and it works fine in Ruby 1.9.3. Can you edit and add a simple test case that does not work for you

Comment: Logically you want yield to be able to handle only one parameter, but you actually pass two. So it's not logically correct, is it?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "prevent". Do you want to silently cancel application of the arguments to `yield`, or do you want to raise an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a splat in the block, or simply pass variables which *may* be there and test for their definition:

```
def foo
  yield 1, 2, 3
end

foo do |*args|
  if 3 == args.length
    # ... then I know I'm dealing with 3 args
  end
end

foo do |a, b, c, d|
  if !d.nil?
    # ... then I know i was passed `d`
  end
end
```

Comment: But that requires the caller (the one defining the block) to be responsible for checking the arguments the block is given, whereas it sounds like the question is asking how the method being called could raise an error when it is given a block accepting the wrong number of arguments... unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: I understood it as the reverse, but perhaps I'm the one misunderstanding.  It made sense to me because when authoring the method you know what you're yielding, but when consuming a yield there's no clear way to tell how many arguments will be passed to your block.

Comment: Right, agreed. And in my answer I was trying to clarify to @user1229490 that with method blocks, there's really no way to indicate that, meaning you would need to use one of the other types of closure such as a lambda (although you lose the syntactic sugar).

Answer (score 0):

See this excellent blog post on Ruby Blocks, Procs, and Lambdas:

> [Understanding Ruby Blocks, Procs and Lambdas](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)

It explains that Blocks (such as the one being passed in `foo()  {|p1,p2| ...}`) act like [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html)s, which do not check the number of arguments passed. Lambdas do, however. So if you require strict checking of the number of arguments, you could potentially switch from accepting a Block in your method to accepting a Lambda as a method argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a block argument instead of `yield`, which provides more information than `yield` such as arity.

```
def foo *params, &block
  ...
  block.call(*params) if params.length == block.arity
  ...
end

foo(3){|x| puts x*3} # => 9
foo(3, 4){|x| puts x*3} # => Does not do anything
```